# Combine and compress CastleProject MonoRails' formhelper.js and behaviour.js?

Tags: javascript, optimization, castle-monorail

Anyone who works with CastleProject MonoRails MVC who knows if I can combine and/or compress formhelper and behaviour js files together into something like monorails.js?

I want to get the amount of webrequests as low as possible..

Answer (score 1):

If loading the two javascript files together on one page isn't a problem then you'll get the same behavior out of concatenating them into a single file.  While you're at it you can minify them as well: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/

Answer (score 1):

Peter's answer is good but there is a [.NET implementation of YUI Compressor](http://www.codeplex.com/YUICompressor). I think it will be more preferable and useful for .Net projects.

Answer (score 1):

I did this a while ago.

http://theusualsuspect.com/all-things-net/simple-js-and-css-compression-for-monorail

Answer (score 0):

Castle MonoRails has a buildt in CombineJS component that works as a javascript combiner with a name (key). Note that the path will be relative, so we should never have more than 2 combinejs blocks in order to keep the httprequests < 2 (IE7 max parallel http requests).

```
#blockcomponent(CombineJS with "key=scripts") 
    $combiner.Add("my/script.${ext}")
#end
```

PS! If anyone knows how to change the domain (not relative), let me know :-)